# Python 3 parsing iTunes library plist file using plistlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, plist

I'm trying to parse a iTunes media library file, which is a plist file using python & plistlib. I wrote a simple python script:

```
import plistlib

plist = plistlib.readPlist('tunes.xml')
print(plist['Tracks'])
```

But when I try and run it an error occurs on line 3:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 21970: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried to load the file with a utf-8 encoding convert to a `bytearray` and use `plistlib.readPlistFromBytes` but still the error occurs

Which is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Which statement do you get the error with (the "line 3" mentioned above)?  And in what environment are you running this?  (OS X, Windows - terminal session, IDLE)

Comment: `print(plist['Tracks'])` is where the error occurs. I'm using Linux (Arch Linux).

Comment: On OS X + Python 3.3 or 2.7, your code works straight out without codec support. Under Python 2.6, I need codec. I suspect it is in the Python / Linux combo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are the terminal session or console you're running this in is not set to a UTF-8 compatible `locale`.  See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale for more info.  For example, in US English locales:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```